# how to feed filename as string to grep so that it searches for the pattern inside the file?

Tags: regex, grep

```
ls local* | tail -1
```

gives a file name for example localhost.txt. I want grep to search for pattern inside this file and not in the filename string. The following doesnt work since it looks for pattern in the filename string rather than inside the file.

```
ls local* | tail -1 | grep -Eo 'pattern'
```

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your filename doesn't contain any whitespaces/glob etc characters, you can `xargs`:

```
ls local* | tail -1 | xargs grep -Eo 'pattern'
```

Or using command substitution:

```
grep -Eo 'pattern' $(ls local* | tail -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like

cat $(ls local*) | grep -Eo 'pattern'

Comment: Thanks! this works. can you tell me what $() after cat does? thanks!

Comment: `cat` is unnecessary here and what happened to `tail`

Comment: $() is used for command substitution,  (so you basically take the output of ls local* and  pass it as agruments to cat which you can then pipe to grep. ) anubhava - in my order cat is necessary, in your example, it is not as you pass the command substitution results directly to grep

Comment: Also tail -1 is if you want only the last result of the matching files, my example checks all of the matching files.